# Rails - submit and index on same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I would like to know if there is any way that I can use my index page as submit page too.

for example i want be able to submit post and list already exists posts on same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can display a form with `form_for` helper in your index view.

Your `index` action in `posts_controller.rb` should look like this:

```
def index
  @post = Post.new
  @posts = Posts.all
end
```

Your `view/posts/index.html.erb` view should look like this:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title, "Post title" %>
  <%= f.text_field :title%>

  <%= f.label :content, "Content" %>
  <%= f.text_field :content%>

  <%= f.submit "Add"%>
<% end %>

<%= render @posts %>
```

Then you have to create a partial called `_post.html.erb` in the `view/posts` folder in order to display the html for every single post.

Note that you still need a `create` action in your `posts_controller`, something like:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  redirect_to root_path
end

  private

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
    end
```

Let me know if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely wrong. Instead of routing all the POSTs and GETs to one method, you should read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html):

Basically, you'll change your page to post data to a new method via ajax and replace the div element with a partial.